# Why does Java 8 Nashorn (JavaScript) modulo returns 0.0 (double) instead of 0 (integer)?

Tags: javascript, java-8, modulo, nashorn

Consider following code sample:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

public class Tester {

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      ScriptEngine se = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName( "nashorn" );

      Object eval = se.eval( "5%5" );

      System.out.println( "eval = " + eval );
      System.out.println( "eval.getClass() = " + eval.getClass() );
  }
}
```

Why it produces the following output?

> eval = 0.0
>   eval.getClass() = class java.lang.Double

The result type is `java.lang.Double` which is **weird**.

In case the remainder is different than 0 it correctly returns `java.lang.Integer`, e.g. `5%2` returns `java.lang.Integer' with value`1`.

Only 0 is somehow *special*.

Trying the same JavaScript expression in Firefox 32.0.2 (FindBugs console) works fine and returns plain 0.

Is there any way to force Nashorn to return Integer type instead of Double?

Comment: JavaScript has only float type of numbers.

Comment: @Teemu thanks for your input, but why does it matter here? Internally it might be a float, but somehow it's able to 'cast' it to integer, e.g. `5%2` produces integer 1. I would accept such explanation if I'd get 1.0 in this case.

Comment: Firefox is not "casting" anything. It's just a matter of how it's displaying the floating point value 1.0.

Comment: Ok, I think we're a bit off the track here. Forget about the casting / Firefox etc. The question still valid is why `5%2` results in `java.lang.Integer(1)` and `5%5` results in `java.lang.Double(0.0)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no integers in JavaScript.

Start with [ECMAScript Section 8: Types](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8):

> The ECMAScript language types are Undefined, Null, Boolean, String,
>   Number, and Object.

Then see [ECMAScript Section 8.5: The Number Type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5):

> The Number type has exactly 18437736874454810627 (that is, 264−253+3) values, 
>   **representing the double-precision 64-bit format** IEEE 754 values ..." (emphasis added)

The fact that Firefox displays the floating point value 1 as "1" rather than "1.0" is irrelevant, and is confusing you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let's forget the Firefox as I agree it might confuse. Let's just focus on Nashorn that should implement the ECMAScript LS. Sometimes it's `java.lang.Integer` and sometimes it's `java.lang.Double`.

Comment: Great: thanks for narrowing the question to that ... question. Here's what I'd say: it's odd that it ever returns `java.lang.Integer` given that all JavaScript numbers are floating-point. I'll see if I can figure that part out. I'd say it's a bug, possibly will change in future releases, and thus I'd probably wrap my stuff in something that converts everything to Double (don't have Java API in front of me, but new Double() or Double.valueOf() or whatever).

Comment: Or, to be clearer, I'd change the question from "why does it return Double instead of Integer" to "why does it return Integer instead of Double?"

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot David. So probably the distinction between result type being Integer or Double that implementors of Nashorn did is quite misleading. I would expect it to work consistently - either it should do the conversion all the time (so in above question it should be always `java.lang.Integer`) or it should omit any conversions and just return `java.lang.Double`.

Comment: Yes. I had a look at the code and the design makes it appear, at my level of study, that returning a Double is probably the intent. See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/nashorn/jdk8/nashorn/file/18edd7a1b166/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/codegen/types/NumberType.java for the source code; the return value of `rem` (which implements %) is Type.NUMBER, which if you visit (same package) Type.java you will see is associated with Double. But you'll see in NumberType we get into bytecode-land with all the visitInsn and OpCode stuff, which is where I get off for now. :)

Answer (score 6):

8u40 - forthcoming update - source  http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/nashorn fixes this issue. That said, it is better to expect "java.lang.Number" (in the Java interface) type result for numerical calculations and convert using java.lang.Number methods like intValue(), doubleValue() etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! It's really a pity I can't accept all your guys answers. I've accepted David answer as he firstly suggested this is a bug and dig into the source code. Nevertheless, thanks once again.

Answer (score 5):

This is what the [Nashorn docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html#A1147390) have to say about passing numerical values from JavaScript to Java:

> if the target type is less specific (for example, Number), you can only expect them to be of type Number, ... The number can be any boxed type due to internal optimizations

As others already have pointed out JavaScript itself only supports floating point values (the `Number` type).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this "The number can be any boxed type due to internal optimizations" part!