# Addition operation in Nashorn javascript engine -java8

Tags: nashorn

I have 2 variables to add using engine.eval()- nashorn javascript engine in java8.?
I've used code like this:

```
     ScriptEngineManager sem=new ScriptEngineManager();
     ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");
     Integer sum = 20;
     Integer var2=30;
     try { 
        sum=(Integer)engine.eval("sum+var2"); 
     } catch(Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Error executing script: "+ e.getMessage());
     }
```

The eval function takes only string parameter. So it shows error.how to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Nashorn ScriptEngine is a separate runtime. It doesn't have knowledge of data outside it's scope unless **explicitly** specified.

Here sum and var2 are **outside the scope of Nashorn**. You can pass this data to Nashorn via multiple methods. One of them is using **bindings**.

Sample code :

```
ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("nashorn");
Integer sum = 20;
Integer var2 = 30;
try {
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("sum", 20);
    bindings.put("var2", 30);

    double result = (double) engine.eval("sum+var2", bindings);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error executing script: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The type conversion from integer to double is a nuance explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989642/why-does-java-8-nashorn-javascript-modulo-returns-0-0-double-instead-of-0-i).

But this kind of script evaluation is rather limiting. You can use [Invocable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/Invocable.html) api to invoke javascript functions. This [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-nashorn) is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank You Vigneswaran. It really helped me.